# OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to run my flask app to lambda. It deploy successfully (using serverless framework) but when I'm testing I get this error :

`OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system`

Part of the code that trigger the error :

```
with open("tmp/some-file.zip", "wb") as binary_file:
        binary_file.write(file_content)
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: The app is already deployed to lambda. So what's wrong with the permission ?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53810516/getting-error-aws-lambda-erofs-read-only-file-system-open-var-task-assets help? I found it by putting `aws-lambda read-only file system` into a search engine. It was the first result.

Comment: Looking closer: it appears that you know that you need to write to somewhere in the `/tmp` directory, but that means you simply have a typo (or a misunderstanding about absolute vs. relative paths on unix-like systems).

Answer (score 1):

In the provided example, you're using relative path to `tmp`, unless you're working dir is `/`, it will try to open a file in an invalid (not available for write) path. When trying to write to a file in `/tmp` (which is writable for Lambdas), ensure you're providing proper, ideally absolute path.

Comment: I do work from the root directory. So the path provided is right.